# Why does Meteor use fibers rather than promises or async or something else?

Tags: meteor

Why does Meteor use fibers rather than promises or async or maybe left asynchronous calls?
What are the fibers benefits? Can someone explain that architectural decision?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Straight from the horse's mouth](http://www.quora.com/Node-js/Why-is-Meteor-much-more-popular-than-Derby), lead Meteor developer Geoff Schmidt:

> Meteor is focused on giving the best possible experience to the
>   *application developer*. We've had to make some seemingly unpopular or risky decisions to get there, but that has resulted in a set of tools
>   that are simpler, more powerful, and more fun to use. . . . it turns
>   out that these decisions are not nearly as risky or as unpopular as
>   some people might perceive. It would be better to say that they go
>   against the conventional wisdom in the node.js community. To take just
>   one example, the thread-per-request or process-per-request model is
>   very common in the larger software engineering community, whereas
>   node's continuation passing ("asynchronous") style is sometimes used
>   for chat servers and message busses but is almost never used for
>   business logic. I think that server-side JavaScript usage is going to
>   grow by multiple orders of magnitude in the next few years, and we're
>   going to have a massive influx of new developers. Most of the new code
>   that these developers write will be business logic, and they'll want
>   to write it with the straight-line control flow that they've used in
>   almost every other framework.

And to quote [a great article about Fibers in Meteor](http://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html):

> Meteor abstracts Fibers with its APIs, allowing you to write your app
>   without callbacks. The best part is that you can write your code this
>   way and be completely oblivious to Fibers. It *just works.*
>
> Fibers is the one of the best reasons Meteor is so popular. Since it
>   allows us to write Node.js apps without callbacks, it has attracted
>   many developers who hated Node.js for that reason.

In other words, you the developer can create Meteor apps without ever typing the word "Fiber". It all happens in the background. So most developers for most apps really have no reason to care "why Fibers" versus Promise or something else, because the developers aren't "using" any of those technologies directly anyway. The Meteor team could rewrite Meteor core under the hood to use Promises instead of Fibers and most apps should continue running just as before, oblivious to the change.

As for why in the Meteor core itself the core team preferred Fibers over Promises etc., from what I've read (and is hinted at in the Geoff Schmidt quote above) it's mostly their personal preference—i.e. their aversion to callbacks and code that is overly conscious of its asynchronous nature. They want the same callback-oblivious experience for themselves that they create for Meteor application developers.

Comment: That you as a developer doesn't need to be aware of Fibers is only true for very simple Meteor apps. As soon as you want to do something that's asynchronous, like geting a file from S3 or writing a file to disk you'll have to understand Fibers.

Comment: Yes and no. Many "asynchronous" actions like HTTP.post (and waiting for the response) can be coded in a synchronous style. See http://docs.meteor.com/#http and note the text about how `asyncCallback` is optional when running server-side.

Comment: Sure, Meteor provides some wrappers around commands that are usually asynchronous and that can be of great help. Pretty soon it won't be enough though, even in a case where you just want to use HTTP.post. Say you want to do 10 POST requests and then do something with the result. Using the HTTP.post method you'd have to make one request, wait for it to return and then do the next and so on. If you understand Fibers/Futures you can do all the requests at the same time and wait for all of them to return before your code continues. I'd really recommend anyone developing in Meteor to study Fibers.

Comment: Of course, if you **want** your code to behave asynchronously, you'll need to write it in an asynchronous style, using callbacks or Fibers or something else. In my own apps, I've often used `this.unblock()` (http://docs.meteor.com/#method_unblock) and HTTP.post `asyncCallback`; but so far I've never had to use Fibers directly in my code. I think the 'Meteoric' way to do async is to use callbacks, rather than calling Fibers directly; but that's probably not possible (or desirable) in all cases. My point is that you can do a lot—possibly everything you need to—in Meteor without learning Fibers.

Comment: Even though this post is quite old: I found stuff like `if (collection.find({ uniqueValue }).count() === 0) { collection.insert({ uniqueValue }); }` in our codebase which suddenly crashed because there already was a value having this `uniqueValue` because the function was called twice. The developer writing this was 1. not aware of `collection.upsert()` and 2. not aware of the fact that `.count()` actually is async.

Comment: So how does the oppinion of the Meteor authors change in 2022 and further on as there's Node v.16 which makes node-fibers obsolete kinda? Will they rewrite Meteor to move to async/await, will they adjust node-fibers, or will they stick to node v14?

Comment: > So how does the opinion of the Meteor authors change in 2022 and further on as there’s Node v.16 which makes node-fibers obsolete kinda?

For now they’ve taken over node-fibers and will keep patching it to keep supporting Node for as long as they can: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/11791. But long term they plan to refactor to move to async/await.